# Java check if Interface implementation is an object of particular implementation

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot to autowire a list of generic types.

*Processor* is an interface and all of its implementations are being autowired.

I need a particular implementation of that Interface, for which I am using a method which will take the Implementation class type and return the corresponding Implementation which was autowired.

```
@Autowired
private List<Processor> processorsList; //Autowiring all implementation of Processor

// Return an autowired instance of a particular implementation
private Processor getProcessor(Class<? extends Processor> cls) {
    for (Processor p: processorsList)
        if (p instanceof cls) // getting compilation error here
            return p;
    return null;
}
```

I am getting a compilation error here: Uknown class: cls

How to solve this or is there a better way of doing what I am doing?

Comment: [`cls.isInstance(p)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: Regarding "is there a better way": Maybe you can directly inject it into whoever now calls this `getProcessor` method? Where is `cls` from?

Comment: Processor needs to be executed in a certain order which is configured elsewhere. The Processor executor uses getProcessor to get the instances to be executed sequentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No compilation error with the dynamic equivalent to `instanceOf` : `Class.isInstance(Object object)`

```
@Autowired
private List<Processor> processorsList; //Autowiring all implementation of Processor

// Return an autowired instance of a particular implementation
private Processor getProcessor(Class<? extends Processor> cls) {
    for (Processor p: processorsList)
        if (cls.isInstance(p))  return p;
    return null;
}
```

beware to the potential NPE

Answer (score 0):

As you can follow this link which perfectly make restriction of using instanceOf
[Cannot Use Casts or instanceof with Parameterized Types]

**Because the Java compiler erases all type parameters in generic code, you cannot verify which parameterized type for a generic type is being used at runtime:**
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#cannotCast